# WPF PropertyGrid with custom editor with binding with more than one property to the object bound to the PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, propertygrid

I need a WPF PropertyGrid that allows me to use a custom editor, for a single PropertyGrid item, with two or more property that can be binded to the PropertyGrid binded object.

By default an object with two property like `MyModel` will produce in a PropertyGrid two property grid item for each property.

```
public class MyModel

{

   public bool EditName { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

What I would like is to have a single PropertyGrid Item instead with a custom editor that is binded to both the property.

[image: Single PropertyGridItem binded to two Property]Is it possible to do this with some PropertyGrid even a commercial version?
I've seen Telerik and Xceed buth I don't see any example to something like this.